# Eclipse EE keeps randomly decides to exclude /resources folder from build path (Maven)

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, configuration, ide

This is a rather short question, and I have no idea what reproduces it.  As I'm working on a project, Eclipse will suddenly decide to re-exclude my resources folder from the build path with a '**' exclusion in:

Build Path > Configure Build Path > Source > src/main/resources

will randomly pick up a '**' in the Exclusion field.  I always make sure to remove it when I start a new project, but seemingly at random, that exclusion will be thrown back in there. it causes a lot of wasted time chasing bugs that don't exist because I didn't realize that a major part of my project configuration is now being excluded from the build, and I find myself randomly checking it constantly to see if doing some small action or changing a file causes the whole resources folder to suddenly become excluded (wasting more time).  Is there a way to change the value, and make it read-only so that eclipse can stop making me pull my hair out? Thanks!